# Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (runtimeerror) ruby (Ruby, Windows 7)

Tags: ruby, devkit

I keep getting this error every time I try and install curb or curl-multi in the console. I've tried reinstalling devkit and uninstalling and reinstalling curb and curl-multi but it didn't work. Does anyone know what I need to do to get around this error?

Comment: Do you have curl (and all its development headers) installed on your computer?

Comment: I do yes. Absolutely.